# The email address is already in use by another account (Auth With Email/Password Firebase)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using Email/Password Auth From Firebase. And I handle The exception message.
and I First Registered and After That Go To Login Activity But When I Write The Email I am Registered With It .. I can not log in And Get This Error "The email address is already in use by another account".

In Firebase Panel I have the Email That Register By It BUt I can Not Login With It.

[image]

this Is My code Too...First For **Registered**:

```
  private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    /*Firebase Auth*/
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

/*Register With Firebase Auth*/
        fun onRegisterBtnClick(view: View) {



            val dialog: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                this@StudentRegisterActivity, getString(R.string.please_wait),
                getString(R.string.processing), true
            )

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(stuEmail, stuPass).addOnCompleteListener {
                dialog.dismiss()
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.coordinator,
                        getString(R.string.register_succesed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    snackbar.show()


                    /*Intent to Login Activity*/
                    val intent = Intent(this@StudentRegisterActivity, StudentLoginActivity::class.java)

                    startActivity(intent)

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, it.exception.toString())
                    val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.coordinator,
                        it.exception!!.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    snackbar.show()
                }
            }


        }
```

---

and **LOGIN**

```
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth


        /*Firebase Auth*/
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

  fun onLoginBtnClick(view: View) {

            val dialog: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                this@StudentLoginActivity, getString(R.string.please_wait),
                getString(R.string.processing), true
            )

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(stuEmail, stuPass).addOnCompleteListener {
                dialog.dismiss()
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.coordinator,
                        getString(R.string.register_succesed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    snackbar.show()

                    /*Intent to Login Activity*/
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, BatchesStudentActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, it.exception.toString())
                    val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.coordinator,
                        it.exception!!.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    snackbar.show()
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do this inside your clickListener

```
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(stuEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(stuPass)){


                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(stuEmail, stuPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            //give the intent or whatever you want

                        } else {

                            String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error : " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }



                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: Cooolll. Thank ..Work For Me